# Creating Drupal Accounts when a sub-type CiviCRM Contact is created - created by a webform

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm, user-account, drupal-rules, contact-types

I have a scenario - which I have no doubt that others will have come a crossed and some will have implemented.  The scenario is: to have a web form (created via the Webform module - which has CiviCRM fields integrated into it - via the Webform integration module) that has the CiviCRM fields such as:

- the first name,
- the last name,
- the e-mail address, and
- the address
  (e.g. address line 1, address line 2, city, post code) etc

and when the user (**whom is not logged in - as they do not have a Drupal account**)  selects submit

1. The details entered are saved in CiviCRM, but equally
2. A Drupal user is created for the user (*no doubt using the Rules module in Drupal*).

**The issue is that**

1. I’d only want the rule fired if the web form was used, not if I create users via the CiviCRM admin interface (as I have sub-type contacts which wouldn’t need Drupal accounts assigned to them)
2. When I go into Rules - I can find the triggering event, which i assume would be “CiviCRM Contact: Contact has been created” e.g. when a Contact is created the rule will begin to fire…

[image]

***what I’m not sure about is:***

2a. how to configure the condition for the rule to say “**only do the action** if the contact is of sub-type x” or if triggered by webform x

2b. how to **configure the action portion** of the rule to create a new Drupal user

2)b)i. there is the “Create a new entity” option under the Entities section in the drop down for action to add, where i can choose “User” as the value …

*Image 2: The rules screen - where trigger specified in top section*

[image]

*Image 3: The options user the actions options*

[image]

**however**, on the next screen - where it asks for the login name of the user, the replacement patterns do not provide me with a means of saying use the e-mail entered in the registration form as the User name for the account that I want created; **nor** does it allow me to specify that the system should pick up the e-mail entered in the web form as use that as the email address for the new account being used.

- **side note:** I do realise at this point having written the above that the rule was written saying do x when event y is triggered - and without specifying that event y should be coming from webform a, which might explain why the action portion of the rule is not providing any replacement pattern for the username - e.g the rule is generic so would be fired if a contact record was created via a different form or the general CiviCRM admin panel.

So… anyone got any ideas on how to achieve what I’m trying to do above?  I assume I can do the above without having to get involved with writing bespoke modules or using hooks etc.

Comment: Ok it looks like I can use the Webform Rules module to restrict the firing of an action to a Webform ... this might address aspect 2)a) in the question...

Answer (score 2):

Most of what you need is here: [How can I create a Drupal user when someone submits a CiviCRM-Webform?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/11768/how-can-i-create-a-drupal-user-when-someone-submits-a-civicrm-webform) based on [@petednz-fuzion's blog post](https://civicrm.org/blog/petednz/creating-drupal-users-made-easy-for-single-or-multiple-contacts-via-civi-imports-and).   It uses [civicrm_entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity) which has seen a lot of activity since the previous question so there may be some changes but hopefully nothing that prevents you following it.

For limiting action to a specific contact sub-type, add a new Condition using 'Data comparison' with a data selector of `civicrm-contact:contact-sub-type`

Comment: Hi Aidan... Thanks for the info and taking the time to look into the issue I am having... an interesting approach will see if it resolves my issue in totality... on a side note: since posting my question I was able to use create entity - then select User to create a Drupal user - however, it only seems to work when I statically assign the username and e-mail values not when I tell it too use the values provided in the form fields e.g. [data: {component}-value]

Answer (score 2):

Ok so the installation and use of the Webform Rules went a long way to contributing to resolve the issue in terms of restricting the triggering of the action of creating a user and also providing the webform fields to the rule process...

And Aidan's info seemed like a possible solution and provided another way of doing things (but, I think, as pointed out by Aidan a lot has moved on since that information was published and so some of the options are no longer available in their former guise).

... Then there was info from @Pierre.Vriens see the thread posted here:

[Webform Rules - Create a Drupal User](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/250929/webform-rules-create-a-drupal-user/250932#250932)

... where the recommendation was to try and use variables to hold the field values and then assign the variable as the value of the Drupal User Entity, which I did and it resolved the second part of the issue.

Thanks to both @Aidan and @Pierre.Vriens for the help on this.